# generate qrcode with base64 php html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

so I have this PHP code to generate QR code in WordPress but some tax roles required the code to be in base64 so I want to make my code work with Hexadecimal Encode 64 and utf8
any help?
my code

```
<?php
        $barcodetype = (get_option('plugindistrict_orderbarcodes_barcodetype') == '' ? 'qrcode' : get_option('plugindistrict_orderbarcodes_barcodetype'));

?>
        <div class="pd_order_barcode_div" style="text-align: right; margin: 40px; ">
         
                 <img class="pd_order_barcode" style="margin-top: -155; margin-right: 50; width:20%  " src="https://2tfh7u96zl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/added-jest-tests/barcode?type=<?php echo $barcodetype.'&value='.(($barcodetype == 'qrcode') ? $checkinpath .'Name:Sleep Blue'.'%0A'.'Tax No:302188012300003'.'%0A'.'Bill NO:'.$this->get_formatted_number().'%0A'.'Date-Time:'.$this->get_formatted_date().'%0A'.'Bill Amt With Vat:'.$order->get_total().'%0A'.'Vat Amt:'.$order->get_total_tax(): $order).'&includeText='.(get_option('plugindistrict_orderbarcodes_showtextupc') == 1 ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>" />

``
```

Comment: What have you tried to make it work? What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: I want to make the code generate the QR with base64, the  PHP code work without problem just want to add some lines to make  it  generate base64

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If everything works without problem, what is your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to generate a dynamic QR code and display.
you may use the google API which you don't need to convert into base64 / save the file.

To use this , basically:

> https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8

**300x300** is the size of the QR image you want to generate,
the **chl** is the url-encoded string you want to change into a QR code, and
the **choe** is the (optional) encoding.
The link, above, gives more detail, but to use it just have the src of an image point to the manipulated value, like so:

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com" />
```

Result.

[image]